# BotFramework: Passing additional values via SuggestedActions

Tags: botframework

I am currently working on a dialog (BotFramework 3.x), that asks the user a span of two numbers. The user should have the option to say "indifferent" if he does not care or it is open end.

So my approach is to have a variety of suggested actions plus an "indifferent" value. The ActionButton should show and write "indifferent" in the chat window but pass a specific int value to the backend:

```
if (actions != null)
    message.SuggestedActions = new SuggestedActions()
    {
        Actions = new List<CardAction>(actions)
    };
    message.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
```

And this is how I build together the actions:

```
                CardActions = new List<CardAction>();

            for (int i = fromTo.from ?? MinValue; i <= MaxValue; i++)
            {
                CardActions.Add(new CardAction()
                {
                    Title = i.ToString(),
                    Value = complexObject,
                    Text = i.ToString(),
                    DisplayText = i.ToString(),
                    Type = ActionTypes.PostBack

                });
            }
        cardActions.Add(new CardAction()
        {
            Title = "indifferent",
            Value = indifferentValue,
            Text = "indifferent",
            DisplayText = "indifferent"
            Type = ActionTypes.PostBack,
        });
```

I am able to get the value in the backend - that is not the problem. What is a problem though is, that the user is not shown hin answer. I want him to see, that he tapped "5" or "indifferent" in the chat history. With `ActionTypes.PostBack` this does not work. If I use `ActionTypes.ImBack` I am not able to use a complex JSON object as value - I simply don't get a response in the backend when tapping the suggestedAction. It only works with `ActionTypes.ImBack` if I use a plain value. But then the chat history shows the value of the action and not the text or displayText, which would make much more sense.

What am I overseeing here??

Answer (score 1):

> If I use ActionTypes.ImBack I am not able to use a complex JSON object as value - I simply don't get a response in the backend when tapping the suggestedAction.

To achieve your requirement: display user selection in chat window, you can specify `ActionTypes.ImBack` and serialize the specified object to a JSON string, like below.

```
CardActions.Add(new CardAction()
{
    Title = i.ToString(),

    //serializes to a JSON string
    Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(complexObject),
    Text = i.ToString(),
    DisplayText = i.ToString(),
    Type = ActionTypes.ImBack

});
```

Besides, to present buttons/options that the user can tap to provide input, you can also use [rich cards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#add-a-hero-card-to-a-message) or `PromptDialog.Choice`.

```
PromptDialog.Choice(
    context: context,
    resume: ChoiceReceivedAsync,
    options: myoptions,
    prompt: "Hi. Please Select an option:",
    retry: "Selected option not avilabel . Please try again.",
    promptStyle: PromptStyle.Auto,
    descriptions: desforchoices
    );
```

***Test result:***

[image]

Comment: The point is, when I use this:
         cardActions.Add(new CardAction()
         {
                Title = i18n.GetString(context.Activity, i18n.FromTo_Indifferent),
                Value = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(indifferentValue),
             Text = i18n.GetString(context.Activity, i18n.FromTo_Indifferent),
             DisplayText = i18n.GetString(context.Activity, i18n.FromTo_Indifferent),
             Type = ActionTypes.ImBack,
            });
the user is shown "indifferent" on the button but when he clicks the button it shows the value in the chat history (0 and not indif)